# Determining the set of characters on $C_\infty(X)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be locally compact hausdorff, but not compact. Consider $C_\infty(X) \subset C_b(X)$ with the sup norm. I know that $C_b(X)$ is an unital banach algebra, and that $C_\infty(X)$ is an ideal that does not contain the unit i.e. $1 \not \in C_\infty(X)$.

I can utilize one point compactification by adding a point $\infty$ to make a compact topology since $X$ is locally compact hausdorff, then our new topology is also hausdorff(I am not gonna prove this). Label our new compact hausdorff space as $\tilde{X}$

Now consider the character $phi:C(\tilde{X}) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$, which is an unital homomorphism. I determined that $\Phi_{C(\tilde{X})}$(set of nonzero characters) is the set of one point evaluations i.e. given any $\phi \in \Phi_{C(\tilde{X})}$, then there exists $x \in \tilde{X}$ such that $\phi(f) = f(x)$ for any $f \in C(\tilde{X})$. I am not gonna go into the proof, but the reason behind this is that $\tilde{X}$ is compact(which we constructed it to be)

I am trying to determine $\Phi_{C_\infty(X)}$(the set of nonzero characters on $C_\infty(X)$), or at least what type of homomorphisms are in it(since $C_\infty(X)$ is not unital, then just consider the homomorphisms) I think I might be able to utilize $\Phi_{C(\tilde{X})}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $C_\infty$?  The algebra of continuous functions that vanish at infinity?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes $C_0(X) or $C_\infty(X)$ sorry about the notation